# Python Pandas DataFrame Difference Between Masking Left side only and Both Side

Tags: python, dataframe, masking

Lets say we have a pandas dataframe like bellow,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'col1':'a', 'col2':'b'}, {'col1':None, 'col2':'d'}, {'col1':'e', 'col2':'f'}, {'col1':None, 'col2':'1'}])
```

Is there any difference between this two code,

```
df.loc[~df['col1'].isnull(), 'col1'] = df['col1'].str.upper()
print(df)
```

vs

```
mask = ~df['col1'].isnull()
df.loc[mask, 'col1'] = df[mask]['col1'].str.upper()
print(df)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "difference"?

Comment: In the above case, both approaches returns same result. What I would like to know that if there is any case where above two approaches will return different result.

Comment: Those two approaches will return the same result in all cases.

Comment: @andrew_reece thanks.